# ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API integration testing after migration to minimal hosting model

Tags: c#, integration-testing, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

ASP.NET Core 6.0 introduces a new minimal hosting model:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0

After switching to the minimal hosting model, I wonder how to migrate the `IWebHost` building to be compatible with the new minimal hosting model.

Sample how we are currently building our `IWebHost` for integration tests (.NET 5):

```
ServiceDescriptor[] grabbedServices = null;

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        //some configuration here
    })
    .UseDefaultServiceProvider(x => x.ValidateScopes = true)
    .ConfigureTestServices(services => { grabbedServices = services.ToArray(); })
    .Build();
```

As after switching to minimal hosting model we do not have `Startup` anymore, this does not compile.
I sense that we should replace the `UseStartup<Startup>` part with `Configure`? If so, what's  the correct way how to construct the `IApplicationBuilder`?
Maybe there is some other way to build `IWebHost`?